# Pin header in scroll view but embed elements above header

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I would like to make a scrollable view where an element in the view is pinned to the top. The element pinned to the top of the scroll view is not technically the header of the view, though.

I want elements within the scroll view to rest above the header, when the user swipes downwards the elements above the header will disappear to the top while the header stays pinned on the screen (something like twitters profile view).

My current code doesn't pin the header at the top.

```swift
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                Color.blue.frame(width: 50, height: 500)
                Color.red.frame(width: 50, height: 500)
                Color.blue.frame(width: 50, height: 500)
                
                Section {
                    ScrollView {
                        //more content 
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("My Messages")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update

```
Section(header: Text("My Messages")) {
    // Elements that will scroll above the header
    Color.blue.frame(width: 50, height: 500)
    Color.red.frame(width: 50, height: 500)
    Color.blue.frame(width: 50, height: 500)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation uses `Section` with `pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]`, but the inner `ScrollView` might be causing an issue with the layout. You would need to make sure the "`My Messages`" header is pinned while allowing other content to scroll above it.

Try and place the header ("`My Messages`") *outside* the `Section` so that it becomes a standalone element in the [`LazyVStack`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvstack).
Add the content that should appear above the header as separate elements in the `LazyVStack`, and make sure the header element (i.e., "`My Messages`" Text view) is always visible and pinned to the top.

That would be:

```swift
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                // Section for pinned header
                Section(header: Text("My Messages").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                        .id("Header")) {
                    // Elements that will scroll above the header
                    Color.blue.frame(width: 50, height: 500)
                    Color.red.frame(width: 50, height: 500)
                    Color.blue.frame(width: 50, height: 500)
                }

                // More content below the header
                ForEach(0..<20) { _ in
                    Color.green.frame(width: 50, height: 100)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The "`My Messages`" text is now a separate element within the `LazyVStack`, and should stay pinned at the top of the screen.
The colors (blue and red) above the header should scroll off the screen when you swipe downwards, while the header remains fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. I added a small update section in my question with a snippet of code. If you replace the text element in your solution with the code snippet then your solution works.

Comment: @ahmed Good catch, I have updated the code of the answer accordingly.